# Thread synchronization over a static lock when accessing a shared resource

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to fix a issue with thread synchronization from two threads that both access one resource. In this example, that resource is the `Engine`

Here two starts are starting the engine, and one of the threads are stopping it. The *goal* is to have a end result of the *engine being started*

**To clarify:** I don't control the code in ThreadOne/ThreadTwo, and would need the synchronization to go in the `Lifecycle` class.

What's the best way to achieve that in this example?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(ThreadOne).Start();
        new Thread(ThreadTwo).Start();

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void ThreadOne(object obj)
    {
        Lifecycle.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Lifecycle.Stop();
    }

    private static void ThreadTwo(object obj)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(600);
        Lifecycle.Start();
    }
}

class Engine
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Engine was started");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Engine was stopped");
    }
}

static class Lifecycle
{
    private static readonly object LockObject;
    private static Engine Engine;

    static Lifecycle()
    {
        LockObject = new object();
        Engine = new Engine();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            Engine.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(800);
        }
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            Engine.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the last thing that happeneds to be thread 2 starting the engine?

Comment: But it is possible for thread 2 to run `Start` before thread 1 executes the `Stop` method?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, it is. In this example, it'll start the engine twice, and then stop it once. Rather than Start, Stop, Start

Comment: By the looks of it you want all of the actions to happen sequentially.  There is never any point in time in your program where each thread should be doing something at the same time, nor do you want any of the actions to be interwoven.  The solution is therefore clearly to remove all of the additional threads and just run the program sequentially.  You're adding in a bunch of threading overhead for literally zero benefit.

Comment: There is no need for all the thread overhead, as it looks like you simply want to run these two method synchronously.

Comment: @Servy that argument fails as soon as you replace Sleep() with something more realistic.

Comment: @Servy The example is a dumbed down example. I don't have control over the threads here (in fact, they are OS threads). The only thing I can control is the synchronization.

Comment: Thanks everybody, your answers, specially the deleted ones were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not replace the `lock`s with directly accessing the Monitor's methods instead?

```
internal static class Lifecycle
{
    private static Engine Engine;

    static Lifecycle()
    {
        Engine = new Engine();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(Engine);
        Engine.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(800);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        Engine.Stop();
        Monitor.Exit(Engine);
    }
}
```

Comment: @scott4dev - Sure, you can lock on the `Lifecycle` type. However, if you ever needed multiple locks for some reason, you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens-MSFT He didn't suggest locking on `LifeCycle`.  That would be a *terrible* idea.  He suggested locking on `Engine`, which is *very* different.

Comment: @Servy - Thanks, TIL I can't read. That makes far more sense, I don't see many people suggest to lock on the type (easy way to get a deadlock situation).

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens-MSFT now your solution is equal to mine and you post it later

Comment: @scott4dev - I can't help you with that (can't even delete it, since it's marked as the answer). Ask OP to mark yours instead. The points don't mean anything to me.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens-MSFT no problem. I will survive :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to call `Start` multiple times without actually start it second time then

```
private static bool _isStarted

public static void Start()
{
   if(!_isStarted)
   {
       _isStarted = true;
       ...
   }
}

// set to false in Stop()
```

This has race condition problem. I used simple variable to give an idea.

If you goal is to call what was the last, then it's simply achieved like this:

```
static int _counter;

// thread 1
Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter); // instead of start
... // sleep?
Incterlocked.Decrement(ref _counter); // instead of stop

// thread 2
Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter); // instead of start
... // sleep?

// after all threads are finished, check _counter
// positive - means Start()
```

Comment: No, the goal is to execute Start, Stop, Start, without missing either.

Comment: I am confused now what you need. In comments you say `In this example, it'll start the engine twice, and then stop it once. Rather than Start, Stop, Start` which makes me think you are fighting overheads with unnecessary call. But now you state that you don't want to miss calls. Do you want some sort of queue for them or what?

Answer (score 0):

Now Lifecycle manages the synchronization

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(ThreadOne).Start();
        new Thread(ThreadTwo).Start();

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void ThreadOne(object obj)
    {
        Lifecycle.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Lifecycle.Stop();
    }

    private static void ThreadTwo(object obj)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(600);
        Lifecycle.Start();
    }
}

class Engine
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:O} [{1}] Engine was started", DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:O} [{1}] Engine was stopped", DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}

static class Lifecycle
{
    private static Engine Engine;

    static Lifecycle()
    {
        Engine = new Engine();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(Engine);
        Engine.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(800);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        Engine.Stop();
        Monitor.Exit(Engine);
    }
}
```